# Fetching data sent by lightstreamer

Tags: ajax, lightstreamer

I'm **using** (not programming) an application that sends my browser, using a technology called "lightstreamer" (which i have no clue about), data every second or so (I guess using AJAX?). these are constant changing stock values.

Now... is there any program/thing I can use to automatically fetch/sniff/whatever the raw data that my browser gets, so that for example i could later paste it to Excel and create charts?
Why not just copy the data from the browser window you might ask, and the reason is that the application always shows me only the last 20 values for a given stock, and i wish to automatically get, let's say, the last 1,000 values and throw it to Excel.

Thanks :)

PS I see that the app is written in asp id it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way that I know of to (easily) reconstruct sniffed Lightstreamer communications into tabular data. Lightstreamer pushes updates to the client using a hidden IFRAME, but those updates are efficient, but intended for consumption only by the Lightstreamer client code.

Developers using the Lightstreamer Javascript API can easily hook into update events if they wish to.

However as an application user, you are best off raising a change request with the application owner to add some form of Excel export functionality.

Comment: Could you  provide a sample code (in javascript) to get data from a LightStreamer client? some kind of event handler for getting live messages.